# non-evaluated vignettes with knitr::rmarkdown_notangle

Tags: r, knitr

The `knitr` package has relatively recently added new `notangle` vignette engines, such as `knitr::rmarkdown_notangle`, that allow disabling of evaluation of vignette chunks. The general process of using `knitr` for vignettes is described [here](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/vignette/), while the specific `notangle` functionality is described in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927325/r-cmd-check-does-not-respect-selective-code-evaluation-in-knitr-code-chunks).

My problem is that I can't get this to work.  I can get it to pass `R CMD build` by including the `.html` output in the `vignettes` directory (I also put a copy in `inst/doc`), but I can't get it to pass `R CMD check` unless I specify `--no-build-vignettes`, or unless I change the `rmarkdown_notangle` engine back to `rmarkdown`.

I have built a trivial package that contains the following vignette (in `vignettes/notangle.rmd`): it's available [here](http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/R/misc/notangle_0.0.1.tar.gz).

````
<!--
%\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown_notangle}
%\VignetteIndexEntry{Supplementary Materials}
-->
A silly little vignette.

```{r}
2+2
```
````

My `DESCRIPTION` file includes

```
Suggests:
    knitr,
VignetteBuilder: knitr
BuildVignettes: yes
```

When I try to run `R CMD check` I get

```
* checking re-building of vignette outputs ... NOTE
Error in re-building vignettes:
   ...
Error: processing vignette 'notangle.rmd' failed with diagnostics:
Failed to locate the ‘weave’ output file (by engine ‘knitr::rmarkdown_notangle’) 
   for vignette with name ‘notangle’. The following files exist in directory ‘.’:
   ‘notangle.rmd’
```

Using r-devel (2014-09-17 r66626), but also happens with 3.1.1.

The workaround (which I would strongly prefer to avoid) is to switch from R code chunks to generic code chunks (opens with triple-backtick, rather than triple-backtick+"r"), which Rmarkdown doesn't process.

I'm sure I'm doing something boneheaded.  Any clues?

**update**: I can get what I need (stop all chunks from being evaluated) by explicitly adding `eval=FALSE` to the options of every chunk, but I'd still like to know what's going on ...

Comment: Sorry, it is a knitr bug... I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug in the current version of knitr, and it has been [fixed](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/6a22d28db3e999494c3a964286c9a6588e042464) in the [development version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr) 1.7.9, which will (hopefully) be v1.8 on CRAN in the future.