# Computationally heavy R vignettes

Tags: r, package, knitr, cran

I'm currently converting an JSS article, which uses `knitr`, to an R *package vignette*. However, I'm in doubt on the vignette placement, structure, and how I should handle the very long computation times it requires which is ~2 days on a ordinary laptop.

The [official documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Writing-package-vignettes) offer little to no information regarding this.
A short note in an answer in the [mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-July/061525.html) is the only information I find when searching. Brian Ripley writes here:

> In particular, CRAN does accept packages with Sweave vignettes that 
>   take too long to check -- one takes ca 8 hours [...].  We just ask that we are told so on submission.

[Hadley Wickham's description](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/vignettes.html) of vignettes says to set `eval = FALSE` as the chunk option. However, this is not a viable approach in my case as the generated data from the computations are needed.

[This presentation](http://kbroman.org/Tools4RR/assets/lectures/08_rpack.pdf) suggests that `/inst/doc` are to be used for pre-compiled and heavy vignettes. However, that do not agree very well with the new guidelines on using `/vignettes` for package vignettes (or what?).

Currently, I've placed my source files in `/vignettes` and I create an `.RData` file which contains the most computationally expensive objects (and which is also quite large). The scripts then check if the objects are available through that `.RData` file, if not, the objects are created. So to compile and run completely from scratch, the `.RData` file  can simply be deleted.

Do anyone have some experience or pointers regarding this problem?
Should the vignette be in `/vignettes` or `/inst/doc`? 
If the former is preferred, where do I place the needed files such as `.bib`, `.RData`, etc.?
I must admit I find the `/vignettes` vs `/inst/doc` somewhat confusing.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is really a CRAN policy question, not a programming question. The best answer is going to come from an email to CRAN. You might also try r-devel, but I suspect they'll tell you to just ask CRAN, too.

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, I see that now. I guess this also was an attempt to avoid bothering the CRAN maintainers (which I'm sure already have far too little time) and to hear if and how others have handled similar problems. If it's not inappropriate, I'll leave the question here and email the maintainers later if nothing comes up.

Comment: Makes sense. If you do get an answer from CRAN, I'd encourage you to post the response here so others can find it. They're busy people, but it's also their (mostly self-appointed) job to maintain the system, so if their help files aren't clear, it's their responsibility to clarify things.

Comment: I'm running into this same problem. Did you find a solution? My next step is going to be to make the .RData files data files and just grab them for the vignettes.

Comment: I believe this thread is the most relevant. https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2016q1/000748.html

Comment: This is very late, but you could include the results of the computation as attached `data`. Then in the vignette you put `eval = FALSE` and load the data under the hood.

Answer (score 11):

I present the following solution for knitr-based vignettes. I will assume you are using *devtools* for package maintenance. To prevent R from running vignette code during package checks (ie. `R CMD check`) which will let you include computationally heavy vignettes, the vignette must:

1. Employ a vignette engine that does not tangle the R code. In other words, the engine must not produce `.R` files in `inst/doc` when you execute `devtools::build_vignettes()`. The *knitr* package provides engines that do not tangle R code, including `knitr::rmarkdown_notangle` which can be used as a drop in replacement for `knitr::rmarkdown`.
2. Include code that disables chunk evaluation dynamically when it detects that it is being executed within a call to `R CMD check`. This can be achieved by placing code at the top of the vignette that checks the various settings and setting chunk settings using `knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval = ...)` when appropriate. The code shown below was borrowed from the *knitr* package, so many thanks to Yihui Xie for working out how to do this.

Below is an example of a rmarkdown vignette file that uses these two strategies so that it can be built using `devtools::build_vignettes()` and will not have its code executed during `R CMD check`. Note that the code is still executed whilst building the package (eg. which is done during `devtools::build()` and `devtools::check()`).

````
---
title: "example vignette"
output:
  rmarkdown::html_document:
    self_contained: yes
fontsize: 11pt
documentclass: article
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{example vignette}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown_notangle}
---

```{r, include = FALSE}
is_check <- ("CheckExEnv" %in% search()) || any(c("_R_CHECK_TIMINGS_",
             "_R_CHECK_LICENSE_") %in% names(Sys.getenv()))
knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval = !is_check)
```

```{r}
Sys.sleep(100)
```
````

For examples of this approach in the wild, [see this vignette for a developmental package on GitHub](https://github.com/prioritizr/prioritizr/blob/master/vignettes/prioritizr_basics.Rmd).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I just use `rmarkdown_notangle` for one of my packages, and it works for windows but doesn't work for linux nor mac. I met problem similar to this: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726388/non-evaluated-vignettes-with-knitrrmarkdown-notangle>. And I use the latest version of `knitr` which is 1.17 on CRAN. Do you have any idea?

Comment: No idea sorry, `rmarkdwon_notangle` in knitr 1.17 works for me on Ubuntu 16.04. The only thing I can think of is trying the dev version of knitr on Github?

Comment: The above solution worked well for me when checking the package on r-hub and win-builder, but for some reason did not prevent the vignette code being run on Travis CI (r-travis). I found [this blog post](http://www.lyzander.com/r/2017/01/30/cran_travis.html) by @LyzandeR who suggested using the 'purl' knitr option to prevent source code from the vignette being extracted and then tested. The 'purl' option alone worked well in preventing the code from being tested on Travis CI but not on r-hub and win-builder. Combining both solutions did the trick, i.e. setting both 'eval' and 'purl' to FALSE.